# How can i put numbers inside the circles of my slider?

Tags: html, css, slider

I want to make a slider and put buttons that let you switch between the slides under it. These buttons should each have a number centered in them. However, the numbers appear on the bottom right of the buttons. How can I fix this?.

[image: screenshot of problem]

```css
.slider-container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1200px;
}

ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
}

ul.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.slider li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ul.slider li:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}  

.slider-menu li{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block
}

.slider-menu li a{
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: rgb(143, 129, 129);
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <ul class="slider">
      <li id="slide1">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li id="slide2">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li id="slide3">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slider-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#slide1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide3">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 0;` into `.slider-menu li a` style can help you do this